# How to check if a string has at least 6 characters in it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a variable, email.

"Check to see if the email value property is at least 6 characters in length"

How do I do that? I dont even know what to google. I tried searching "require certain amount of characters in a string javascript" and couldnt find anything.

The closest thing I could find was to use indexOf. But still I couldnt find any examples using indexOf.

Heres what I have.

```
if (email != '' && email.indexOf(5) && email.indexOf("@")) {
```

I put 5 because one example I found was an array so I wasnt sure if it applied to this too. The other indexOf is to check if the string also contains @

Comment: Off-topic but, `indexOf` returns `-1` if it cannot be found. `-1` is a truey value (only zero is false). What you want is `.indexOf("@") > -1`.

Comment: *"I dont even know what to google."* -  did you try something like "JavaScript string tutorial"?

Comment: In javascript, Strings are array of characters so you can directly use `.length` function like `email.length` & to check valid email ID go for regular expression instead of doing it all manually.

Comment: "*I dont even know what to google.*" - did you try something like "JavaScript string length"? Read the documentation more carefully, such as that for `indexOf`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as:

```
if(email != null && email.length > 5){
    // Your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
if (email==undefined || email.length<6){
    //Don't have sufficient character 
}else{
    //Have sufficient character 
}
```